# How to Compare two variables in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using the following keywords to compare two variables ${status} and ${command} both of which actually have a URL in them. I am trying to perform some action if both of them are equal but I am getting syntax error when I run them. I am using RIDE.

```
Run Keyword If  |   '${status}'=='${command}'   | Click xyz
```

Please let me know if I need to add more info to this question. I am using RIDE as an IDE.

Editing for error:
I am getting the following error:

```
FAIL : Evaluating expression ''xpath=//*[.='Published']'=='xpath=//*[.='Published']'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Comment: Please show the actual error that you get. Also, is that literally your exact line of code? You seem to be missing pipes at the start of the line.

Comment: I missed pipes at the start of the line while writing here. Although it is what I am using in RIDE. I am adding the error above now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your variables contain single quotes, so you can't use single quotes in the expression. A simple fix is to use double quotes, if you're certain the data will never have double quotes:

```
| | Run Keyword If | "${status}"=="${command}" | Click xyz
```

Of course, you'll have a similar problem if your variables contain double quotes.